# Convert SQL query to LINQ to get column value as xml string

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I have following query in SQL.
I have to write the same query in LINQ which will give the same output as SQL query in XML string format.

This select statement is returning column value as XML

```
SELECT Student.Name 
    FROM   StudentCategoryAssociation Assoc
     JOIN Student ON Assoc.CategoryId = Student.Id
 for xml raw('Category'), root('StudentCategories'), type
```

output of this is:

```
<StudentCategories>
  <Category Name="StudentCategory" />
  <Category Name="Light" />
</StudentCategories>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have to bit more than a simple Linq to get the desired output.I have tried to mock your db with List in following examples.

```
var result = new StudentCategories
               {  
                  Category = associationList
                            .Join(studentlist,
                            a=>a.Id,
                            s=>s.Id,
                            (a,s)=>new Category{Name=s.Name}).ToList()
              };
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentCategories));
var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings{OmitXmlDeclaration = true,Indent=true};
string xmlString;

using(var sww = new StringWriter())
using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww,settings))
{
  serializer.Serialize(writer, result,emptyNamespaces);
  xmlString = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
}
```

Where Categories and StudentCategories are defined as

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Category")]
public class Category {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="StudentCategories")]
public class StudentCategories {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Category")]
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
}
```

The output would be

```
<StudentCategories>
  <Category Name="StudentCategory" />
  <Category Name="Light" />
</StudentCategories>
```